# Is there a way to attach policy tags to a Bigquery table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, access-control

I've been trying to attach **policy tags** to existing BigQuery tables using GCP's Python client libraries but can't seem to find a way.

I'm aware of how to create taxonomies and policy tags within [PolicyTagManager](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/datacatalog_v1/policy_tag_manager.html#module-google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.services.policy_tag_manager)

But I can't seem to attach policy tags.

I found ['google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList'](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList.html#google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList.__init__) but I'm not sure where the tableID gets specified or how will policy tags be attached using this method?

Appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: AFAIK policy tags can only be attached to columns not on tables. If you are okay with attaching them on columns, then you can define the policy tags on [TableFiledSchema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tablefieldschema).

Comment: Also ['google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList'](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList.html#google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList.__init__) confirms and says "Define Policy Tags for a column."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I had intended to ask about Policy tags for columns.
I was able to attach the tags to columns and then update the table.

Comment: I see. You can post your resolution here so the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: @AsadSiddiqui Were you able to attach a policy tag to the table column, programmatically ? I'm exploring Python API's to attach the policy tag to a table column but no luck so far.

Comment: @learner answer's been added; sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption: Keeping column names same before and after updating each with policy tags

Steps:

1. Pull the table using [`get_table()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_table) and iterate over it's schema (list of SchemaField)
2. Create new SchemaField object(s), add parameter values by referring to SchemaField's name/description (from step#1) except for `policy_tags` (type = [PolicyTagList](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList.html#google.cloud.bigquery.schema.PolicyTagList)
   example:
   `google.cloud.bigquery.SchemaField(name=column.name,  field_type=column.field_type, policy_tags=google.cloud.bigquery.PolicyTagList(["projects/some-project/locations/us/taxonomies/123454321/policyTags/180000"]))`
3. Append these new SchemaFields objects into a list and re-assign the table's schema with this new list
4. use [`update_table`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.update_table) to update schema such as:

`google.cloud.bigquery.Client(project = BIGQUERY_PROJECT).update_table(table, ['schema'])`

Answer (score 0):

Using @Asad Siddiqui steps, below code is created.

To update schema automatically using a cloud function in GCP is mentioned below.

Process flow: Upload a csv file in GCS bucket --> Triggers the cloud function with below code & Applys the schema mentioned for tables in the csv file.

**CSV template format:**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()


def pii_auto_apply_policies(event, context):

    # READING INPUT CSV FILE TEMPLATE DATA:
    bucket_name = event['bucket']
    object_name = event['name']
    print(object_name, bucket_name)

    path = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, object_name)
    data = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
    print(data.head())

    for row in range(0, len(data.table_id)):

        table = bigquery_client.get_table(data.table_id[row])  # Make an API request.
        original_schema = table.schema

        # Creating new schema list to create a new one.
        new_schema = list()

        # Looping through originial schema to create a new schema list:
        for schema_row in original_schema:

            # 1st if - appends all other column schemas other than the ones required.
            if schema_row.name != data.field_name_in_table[row] or schema_row.field_type != data.data_type_in_table[row]:
                new_schema.append(schema_row)
                
            # 2nd if - picks only the required column and appends with policy tag resource id.
            if schema_row.name == data.field_name_in_table[row] and schema_row.field_type == data.data_type_in_table[row]:
                new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(name=schema_row.name,
                                    field_type=schema_row.field_type,
                                    policy_tags=bigquery.PolicyTagList([data.policy_tag_resource[row]])))

        print("Schema length for table: {}, before: {}, after: {}".format(data.table_id[row], 
                                                                        len(original_schema), len(new_schema)))

        # Applying the schema to table
        table.schema = new_schema
        table = bigquery_client.update_table(table, ["schema"])
        print("Table updated:{}".format(data.table_id[row]))

    return "OK"
```

Limitations: This doesn't apply for "RECORD" type columns (where there are nested fields). I will update a second version, incase if I found the solution.